# Solr query syntax such like SQL “IN” condition

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

A Solr query problem here.

For example, a group checking query: There’s a string spitted by commas field in Solr, such as “*Group1, Group2, Group3*”. I have parameter which is a list of string, such as “*Group3*”, “*Group4*”, “*Group5*”. 
In this case the document with  “*Group1, Group2, Group3*” need to be retrieved, because “*Group3*” is contains in the field.

It’s like SQL “**IN**”, but I don’t find a way to query such conditions.
The problem is Solr doesn’t allow wildcard as first query.

Any solution for this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. What is the problem of using, say, "q={!lucene}*:*&fq={!lucene q.op=OR}groupField:(Group3 Group4 Group5)"

Comment: Agreed and the OP needs to make certain that the comma-delimited field in Solr is tokenized or multi-valued. Personally I think the latter option (a multi-valued string) is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure the type of the column you are using in your schema is:

`<fieldType name="text_country" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">`

and not:

`<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring me! I use whitespace instead of comma to separate groups. Then query 'groups:Group1 OR Group2' works!